# Can I Use Google Tag Manager in Electron?

Tags: electron, analytics, google-tag-manager

I am trying to integrate [Google Tag Manager](https://tagmanager.google.com/) into an Electron app, 
but it doesn't seem to be working. it seems like gtm codes I planted in the app are NOT sending the analytics data anywhere.

I found [this issue](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/8691) on Electron github repo. Seems like some people are having the same issue.

I wonder if it's impossible at all to integrate GTM on Electron, or is there any way around to do this?

**[Update]**

While reading Alexander Leithner's answer, a further question popped up.

on [Google Tag Manager - Dev Guide - Security](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/devguide#security), it says:

> While most of the tag templates in Google Tag Manager are also
>   **protocol relative**, it's important to make sure that, when setting up
>   custom tags to fire on secure pages, those tags are also either
>   protocol relative or secure.

Does `file://` protocol matters because GTM is protocol relative? Wouldn't it be possible to bypass this with GA's `forceSSL=true` option which can be set on GTM Interface?

**[Final Update]**

I found the perfect answer in this blog post:

- [Run Google Tag Manager And Google Analytics In Local Files](https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/run-google-tag-manager-google-analytics-local-files/).

Thank you Eike Pierstorff, for giving me the hint of setting `storage` to `none`, it led me to this post.

Answer (score 1):

GTM by default used to use the same protocol as the webpage - that's what "protocol relative" means. I.e. there is a bit of code that loads the GTM library, and if this uses the file protocol (as per the embedded wegpage) it will try to load the library as a file, which does not work. However GTM has switched from protocol relative to https by default, so I don't think GTM is your problem here.

You mention Analytics data, and if this refers to Google Analytics then your problem is not with GTM, it is that GA does not work on local files. Google Analytics uses a cookie to store the clientId (which is needed to aggregate individual hits into sessions/users), and since you cannot set cookies on a local file this does not work.

A possible workaround would be to go to your GA tag in GTM, to the "set fields" settings, set "storage" to "none" (which means that no cookie is set) and pass in a clientId manually.

Answer (score 0):

As [this comment by Samuel Attard (MarshallOfSound)](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/8691#issuecomment-280295383), who is an Electron developer, states that Google Tag Manager does not work when the including webpage is loaded using a `file://` URL.

If you'd instead load your application via `http://` (or more preferably via `https://`), you would be able to use Google Tag Manager.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but not everything is clear for me yet. Could you look at the updated question?

Answer (score 0):

Google Analytics uses a cookie to store the clientId that is needed to aggregate individual hits.

Currently installing some npm package that adds cookie support (via localStorage) like https://github.com/heap/electron-cookies solves the problem.